# How do I word this JavaScript method to compare the parameter against the object cast values?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Define a method named roleOf that takes the name of an actor as an argument and returns that actor's role. If the actor is not in the movie return "Not in this movie.". Ex: roleOf("Jessica Chastain") returns "Murph". Hint: A method may access the object's properties using the keyword this. Ex: this.cast accesses the object's cast property.

--Code--

```js
var movie = { // Code will be tested with different actors and movies
   name: "Interstellar",
   director: "Christopher Nolan",
   composer: "Hans Zimmer",
   cast: {
      "Matthew McConaughey": "Cooper",
      "Anne Hathaway": "Brand",
      "Jessica Chastain": "Murph",
      "Matt Damon": "Mann",
      "Mackenzie Foy": "Young Murph"
   },
   roleOf: function(actorName) {

      if (actorName != this.cast){ // My code
         console.log("Not in this movie."); // My code
      } // My code
      else { // My code
      return this.cast[actorName]; 
      } // My code

   }
};
```

I also tried an if statement with actorName != "Matthew McConaughey" || "Anne Hathaway" || etc...
This did not work either.

How do I compare the parameter name to the list of names in cast? I've commented // My code next to my attempt which was unsuccessful. The return this.cast[actorName]; is part of the provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a short-circuit operator, you could just write:

```
return this.cast[actorName] || 'Not in this movie.';
```

Comment: Thank you. New to JavaScript. This was correct. I really seemed to be complicating it more than was necessary.

Comment: What would be an alternative to this if you did not know about short-circuit operators?

Comment: How about a ternary operator? :) `return this.cast[actorName] ? this.cast[actorName] : 'Not in this movie.'` Otherwise, just use a simple if/else that does the same: `if (this.cast[actorName]) { return this.cast[actorName]; } else { return 'Not in this movie'; }`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was easier to understand :) I have not learned about short-circuit operators yet.